# local storage data not being passed to other iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have this application that makes a todo list for the user, Iḿ trying to make the tasks the user inputs into the the to do list be transferred over into another website when they click a the button ¨show To do list¨. However nothing is being displayed when I Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined and cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined after they click the button.

I cant add a code snippet to my code since itś using an iframe so here is a plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/d9tvPbfsn7jyFsKV?preview

Here in more detail is what my code aims to do,

user inputs 1st input > user inputs 2nd task (I haven't added an output place for it in the iframe yet as I got stuck on transferring the 1st input) > user inputs 3rd input (I haven't added an output in the iframe for it yet as well because I got stuck on transferring the 1st input)> a to do list is made and displayed on the page

the user can then click the show to do list and it will show it there in the iframe (which will be on another page if it ends up working)

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
</head>

  <body style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;">
    <form id='ui'>
        <fieldset>

<center>
  <div id="easyAssignments">
      <p>Enter your 1st task</p>
        <input type="text" id="easyA1" name='name1'>
      <button type='submit' id="saveE" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="displayM();">Enter</button>
</div>
<div id="mediumAssignments" style="display:none">
    <p id="inputMText">Enter 2nd Task</p>
    <input class="red" type="text" id="mediumA1">
    <button id="saveM" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="displayH();">Enter<button>
</div>
<div id="hardAssignments" style="display:none">
  <p id="inputHText">List your 3rd assignment</p>
    <input class="red" type="text" id="hardA1">
  <button id="saveH" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="makeToDoList(); displayTDL()">Enter</button>
</div>
<center>

<div text-align="center" id="toDoList" style="display:none">
  <h1>To Do list</h1>

<div class="easy-block" id="easy-block">
<h3>1st Task ✌️:</h3>
<p>
All your easy assignments for the day
</p>
  <input type="checkbox" style="font-size: 30px;" id="toDo1" name="toDo1" value="toDo1"/>
  <label style="font-size: 30px;" class="strikethrough" for="toDo1"><span id="result1"></span></label><br>
</div>


<div class="medium-block" id="medium-block">
<h3>Second Task :</h3>
<p>
All your medium assignments for the day.
</p>


  <input type="checkbox" style="font-size: 30px;"id="toDo1M" name="toDo1M" value="toDo1M"/>
  <label style="font-size: 30px;"class="strikethrough" for="toDo1M"><span id="result1M"></span></label><br>
</div>

<div class="hard-block" id="hard-block">
<h3>Third Task </h3>
<p>
All your hard assignments for the day.
</p>

  <input type="checkbox" style="font-size: 30px;" id="toDo1H" name="toDo1H" value="toDo1H"/>
  <label style="font-size: 30px;"class="strikethrough" for="toDo1H"><span id="result1H"></span></label><br>

</div>


</div>

    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>

 </fieldset>
    </form>

    <p>Below is an iframe to a separate page.</p>
    <iframe src='page1.html'></iframe>
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are your sites on different domains?

Comment: Some ideas to get started: you should probably be using different scripts per file. In `index.html` you're including the same script twice, which also doesn't look right. You can use `localStorage` to pass data between pages of the same origin and  you can use [storage events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) to notify that changes have occured